# How can I export data from Python to .txt?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, triangulation

I am a new Python user and I have a question regarding exporting data from Python. I wrote a code to create a mesh using Delaunay triangulation. For the triangulation I used matplotlib.tri library. I got a plot of a grid and now I would like to save coordinates of nodes and elements. So I saved list of nodes:

```
#saving data
data = np.array([mesh_x, mesh_y]) #mesh_x and mesh_y - nodes that used in triangulation
data = np.transpose(data)
np.savetxt('nodes_data.txt', data, delimiter = ',')
```

Now I want to save elements, each of which contains two nodes because I consider truss-elements. Do you have any suggestions, how can I export elements to .txt file?

[image]

Comment: My answer below is based on a *guess* of what you really want, but I'm not sure if it really is what you want… could you please tell me if my guess was right?

Comment: Your answer was really helpful! I didn't know a command to print edges in the triangulation library. Now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

My best understanding of your question leads me to this answer

```
In [7]: import numpy as np 
   ...: from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation 
   ...: np.random.seed(sum(ord(c) for c in 'gboffi')) 
   ...: x, y = [np.random.random(10) for _ in (0,0)] 
   ...: tri = Triangulation(x, y) 
   ...: print(tri.edges)                                                                  
[[1 0]
 [2 1]
 [4 0]
 [4 1]
 [5 0]
 [5 1]
 [5 2]
 [6 0]
 [6 3]
 [6 4]
 [7 3]
 [7 4]
 [7 6]
 [8 1]
 [8 2]
 [8 4]
 [8 7]
 [9 0]
 [9 3]
 [9 6]]

In [8]:
```

Is this what you want?

---

PS I have read a hidden comment of yours: Abaqus/CAE has **ways better** meshing support.